# UItableview Swipe Delete iOS 11 does not refresh / reload data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to programming. The following code  work with swipe deleting a row but after refreshing the all row list appears back .
I have following code:

```
- (UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIContextualAction *delete = [UIContextualAction contextualActionWithStyle:UIContextualActionStyleDestructive
                                                                         title:@"DELETE"
                                                                       handler:^(UIContextualAction * _Nonnull action, __kindof UIView * _Nonnull sourceView, void (^ _Nonnull completionHandler)(BOOL)) {
                                                                           NSLog(@"index path of delete: %@", indexPath);
                                                                           completionHandler(YES);


                                                                       }];
     delete.backgroundColor = [UIColor  purpleColor]; //arbitrary color

    UISwipeActionsConfiguration *swipeActionConfig = [UISwipeActionsConfiguration configurationWithActions:@[delete]];
    swipeActionConfig.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = NO;

    return swipeActionConfig;

}
```

I am using following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FCell = (favouriteCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"favouriteCell"];
    FCell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    if (FCell == nil)
    {
        FCell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"favouriteCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    FCell.nameLBL.text=[[favDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    FCell.poetLBL.text=[[favDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"poet"];
    return FCell;

}
```

Comment: It does not appear that you are removing the row from any data source.
In the completionHandler where you are logging the index path of the delete, you will need to remove that row from your data source (Array, etc). Otherwise, when your table reloads from the datasource, it will reappear.

Comment: thanks, what would be best way to do it?

Comment: What structure are you using as a data source? Can you share some code from your cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Hi Stephen I have added the code into my question. Thanks

Comment: I posted a full answer below based on the new information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the completionHandler where you are logging the index path of the delete, you will need to remove that row from your data source (Array, etc). Otherwise, when your table reloads from the datasource, it will reappear.

Your `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath` code should look like this:

```
    - (UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UIContextualAction *delete = [UIContextualAction contextualActionWithStyle:UIContextualActionStyleDestructive
                                                                             title:@"DELETE"
                                                                           handler:^(UIContextualAction * _Nonnull action, __kindof UIView * _Nonnull sourceView, void (^ _Nonnull completionHandler)(BOOL)) {
                                                                                NSLog(@"index path of delete: %@", indexPath);
[favDetails removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];                                                  
completionHandler(YES);


                                                                           }];
         delete.backgroundColor = [UIColor  purpleColor]; //arbitrary color

        UISwipeActionsConfiguration *swipeActionConfig = [UISwipeActionsConfiguration configurationWithActions:@[delete]];
        swipeActionConfig.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = NO;

        return swipeActionConfig;

    }
```

This will remove the object from your data source as the row is removed visually from the table.

Comment: Many thanks but it shows an error. I have added code of NSlog in my question.

Comment: I'm not sure how the new code in your question is relevant to the original. I believe my answer resolves your original question.
You should probably open a new question with your error.